# How to write html image tag inside php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to write html image tag inside php but the below code is not working, Please help.

```
<?php 
....
....
echo '<img src="../admin/upload/'<?=$display_img?>" width="120px" height="120px"/>
.....
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the php tags you just need to break out of the string:

```
$width = 120;
echo '<img src="../admin/upload/' . $display_img . '" width="' . $width . 'px" height="120px"/>';
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is not working there is syntax error some where in this line.....

Comment: Fixed up the typo in the answer.

Comment: Fixed the other typo :P

Comment: @CarlMarkham LMAO. Cheers for that. I swear my head was tilted for a second looking at it. +1

Comment: Yeh, quotes can be a pain when there is no syntax highlighting

Comment: echo '<img src="../admin/upload/'.$display_img.'" width="120px" height="120px"/>';  the above is working if i want to make width and height dynamic then what changes should be made in the above code.

Comment: @user3653474: got it?..

Comment: I edited the code to show an example of variable width

Comment: @ Carl Markham: super :)..

Answer (score 0):

1. you are inserting a php code block `<? ?>` when you are already in another.
2. `<?=$display_img?>` the equal sign doesn't belong here and the code is attached to the php tags, so the compiler may not be able to read it. It was better this way `<?php echo( $display_img ) ?>`, of course if you weren't already in php.
3. Echoing is a bit messy for me, I would've exited php first like this.

   ```
   <?php
   ....
   ....
   ?>

   <img src="../admin/upload/<?php echo( $display_img ) ?>" width="120px" height="120px"/>

   <?php
   .....
   ?>
   ```

or here is your original code corrected:

```
<?php 
....
....
echo '<img src="../admin/upload/' . $display_img . '" width="120px" height="120px" />';
// OR 
echo '<img src="../admin/upload/{$display_img}" width="120px" height="120px" />';
.....
?>
```

Comment: Yes, he did not close the php block with `?>` before using another block inside it.

Comment: `echo` is a statement not a function. No need for brackets.

Comment: True, I encourage using brackets for a cleaner look and reading;

Comment: Prior to PHP 5.4.0, this short syntax only works with the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled for using <?=